# Error of creating an object of a protocol type which is inherited from multiple protocols

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

In the following code, there are 3 protocols: `Wheeled`, `Vehicle` and `WheeledVehicle` (inherited from `Wheeled` and `Vehicle`)

```
protocol Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
}

protocol Vehicle {
    var maker: String { get }
    var owner: String {get set}
    var ownerKid: String { get }
}

protocol WheeledVehicle: Wheeled, Vehicle {
  // simply just combine Wheeled and Vehicle
}

class Bike: Vehicle, Wheeled {
let numberOfWheels: Int = 0
var ownerKid: String = "Junior"

var maker: String {
    return "Ford"
}

var owner: String {
    get {
        return "Bob"
        }
        set {
            ownerKid = "\(newValue) Junior"
        }
    }
}


let bike: Bike = Bike()

let wheeledVehicleBike: WheeledVehicle = bike //error: value of type 'Bike' does not conform to specified type 'WheeledVehicle'
```

**Question**: Pretty much the error itself, I don't get it, why value of type `Bike` does not conform to specified type `WheeledVehicle`

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically: **Because it does not conform to it**

For the compiler to know that `Bike` conforms to `WheeledVehicle` you have to specify that. The compiler **will not** just assume that since both conform to the same protocols they can be assigned to each other.

The same way that the following does not work.

```
class A { var a : String = "" }
class B { var a : String = "" }

var a : A = A()
var b : B = a // cannot convert value of type 'A' to specified type 'B'
```

Or even simpler

```
class A {  }
class B {  }

var a : A = A()
var b : B = a // cannot convert value of type 'A' to specified type 'B'
```

The compiler does not care if the two types *look alike* - they have to **be alike**.

What would happen in your example if your `WheeledVehicle` gets a `func` added? Does `Bike` no longer conform to it?

The **only** way to make `Bike` conform to `WheeledVehicle` is to declare it explicitly:  `class Bike : WheeledVehicle`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example and explanation. Very good answer! I understand it much better now

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance only works in one direction.  For example, if `Cat` inherits from `Animal`, then an instance of `Cat` is an instance of `Animal`.  But an instance of `Animal` is not necessarily a `Cat`.

Similarly, in your example, an instance of `WheeledVehicle` is both an instance of `Wheeled` and an instance of `Vehicle`. But something that is both an instance of `Wheeled` and `Vehicle` is not necessarily an instance of `WheeledVehicle`.

One other note: you might find it convenient to use this notation in your code:

```
let wheeledVehicleBike: protocol<Wheeled, Vehicle> = bike
```

That allows you to specify multiple protocols a type conforms to without needing to define an additional protocol just for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip! And also the very vivid explanation.

Comment: `protocol<Wheeled, Vehicle>` +1, didn't know about this.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't assume that "being wheeled" and "being a vehicle" implies "being a wheeled vehicle". It could be the case that your `WheeledVehicle` adds new requirements.

As it currently is, the compiler doesn't do this kind of checked. Honestly, it shouldn't because this introduces a lot of unclear, implicit behavior with little benefit.

You'll have to explicitly make `Bike` to `WheeledVehicle`

Comment: @AMonchilov Thanks for your explanation. So, to make the error away, just let ``Bike`` inherits the ``WheeledVehicle``

Comment: @SLN, Yes, I forgot to add that part. Edited it now.

Comment: @AMonhilov Thanks a lot again, very good learning from your guys :)